# Unity3D display Google Admob slow

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, admob

I intergrated Unity Google Admob plugin for Android but my game takes about 3 seconds to display and close full screen ad. It's make my game ugly.
I think Unity take a time to call native APIs, i'm not sure. I use plugin from Google Team.

Are you have the same thing with me!

Answer (score 1):

Interstitials taking a few seconds to close is a known issue (on Android). I've blamed the performance on Unity though; I tried opening up and closing an empty Activity, not ad related, and it took the same amount of time to close on Android.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I don't think it's a issue on Android because i played some games on Android device and i wasn't saw that problem. It's closed immediately when i pressed close button.

For example:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ketchapp.donttouchthespikes

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluefishsoft.fishSpikes2