# Slow Android native events in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using the AdMob plugin for Unity from here:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins

You can try opening their sample scene or attach their sample script for a quick implementation with these test ad unit values:
Banner: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/BannerExample/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
Interstitial: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/InterstitialExample/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

When I display an interstitial ad and press back or close, it seems like it takes an extra second to close the interstitial and return to my Unity app. Compare this to using AdMob in a native Android application, where it closes instantly.

I see that the unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik setting is true for these touch events/onBackPressed events to even be propagated, but is there a way to make it get sent faster, or cut out some interception on Unity's part? This delay hurts the user experience.

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303207/unity3d-display-google-admob-slow, however I don't see a resolution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to my `<activity>` in the AndroidManifest.xml seemed to do the trick:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

I assume that Unity runs with this theme by default so changing from one theme to another on close caused the slowdown.